# Convert "/" to "-" with rewrite rule

Tags: apache-2.2

I have the following rewrite rule in my server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|static)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

It's main porpuse is **to convert every folder requested to the server into a parameter**. For example, requesting example.com/foo fighters gets converted to example.com/index.php?foo fighters.

Pretty cool, huh? Well, there's one problem. If anyone enters, for example, AC/DC, due to the extra slash. Is there any way to rewrite that / to -, **making it work with the current rewrite rule?**

Comment: Why would the slash be a problem? The rewrite rule you currently have is a very common one. Can you explain your situation bit more?

Comment: It's the way i handle the slashes. Rewriting a single / to a -, if possible, would be much easier than refactoring the whole code after the folder gets converted to parameter.

Comment: can you edit your question to provide examples of what is currently happening and what should happen? For example "the url `/AC/DC` currently maps to `/index.php?/AC/DC`, but should map to `/index.php?AC-DC`.  Meanwhile, what should `/AC-DC` map to?  You definitely shouldn't allow two URLs to map to the same thing, so if there is currently ambiguity, force one to "become" the other, using a separate 301 rule.

Answer (score 1):

Use the B flag to url-encode the parameter.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b